# Do John 1:35-42 & Matthew 10:1-4 describe the same occasion?

Tags: john, matthew, gospels, peter

Is the occasion of Jesus calling Simon in Matthew 10:1-4 the same occasion found in John 1:35-42?

Answer (score 2):

The two incidents in John 1:35-42 and Matt 10:1-4 are at different times in the ministry of Jesus.

- John 1:35-42 is by the lake when Jesus first met Simon Peter and called him to ministry.  The parallel incident in Matthew is Matt 4:18.
- Matt 10:1-15 is after a year or more when the disciples had been trained and Jesus was to send them out on their first missionary tour.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing these three harmonies of the Gospels:

Robertson, A. T. (2009). *A Harmony of the Gospels*. Logos Bible Software.

Lemke, S. W. (2007). *The Academic Use of Gospel Harmonies. In Holman Christian Standard Bible: Harmony of the Gospels*. Holman Bible Publishers.

Aland, K. (2009). *Synopsis of the Four Gospels*. Logos Bible Software.

Basically, they put John 1:35-42 between the temptations Matt. 4:1-11 and Matt. 4:12, and Matt. 10;1-4 between John chapters 5 and 6.

The exception is Aland splits off John 1:42 from John 1:35-41 and puts it with Matt. 10:1-4.